# Getting unknown data with GetLogicalDriveStrings()

Tags: c++, winapi

Using the code below in order to get names of my drives:

```
const DWORD buffer_length = sizeof(DWORD)*CHAR_BIT;
WCHAR buffer[buffer_length] = {0};
GetLogicalDriveStrings(buffer_length,buffer);
std::set<wchar_t> drives_letters;
for(auto e : buffer)
{
    drives_letters.insert(e);
}
```

I'm getting following output as a result (looping over drives_letters):

```
: //what on earth is this?  
C 
D 
E 
F 
G 
I 
\ //and what on earth is this?
```

Comment: Have you tried GetDriveType and see what it returns?

Comment: @dowhilefor just working on it now

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`GetLogicalDriveStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns strings in the form `C:\`. This can be inferred from this documentation passage:

> Each string in the buffer may be used wherever a root directory is
>   required, such as for the `GetDriveType` and `GetDiskFreeSpace` functions.

Since you are putting these characters into a set, which disallows duplicates, you end up with all the different drive letters plus one copy of a double colon and a backslash. And the reason that the colon prints first and the backslash last is that `std::set` is inherently ordered, so the ASCII codes of each character decide.

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop is wrong. You are assuming that `GetLogicalDriveStrings()` returns individual drive letters only, and that is not the case (if you want that, use `GetLogicalDrives()` instead). It returns paths to drive root folders, and as such you need to change your `for` loop the following:

```
const DWORD buffer_length = 104; // can return drive paths A:\ - Z:\
WCHAR buffer[buffer_length+1] = {0}; // room for null terminator

GetLogicalDriveStrings(buffer_length, buffer);
std::set<wchar_t> drives_letters;
for(wchar_t *drive = buffer; *drive != 0; drive += 4)
{
    drives_letters.insert(*drive);
}
```